# Setting url dynamically for outbound gateway doesnt work

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to dynamically set the url for my outbound-gateway element, and it is not working for some reason. Everything worked fine before I tried to set it dynamically.

Here is the relevant part of the xml:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
        request-channel="sumTicketChannelOutput"
        url="{ticketsSum}"
        http-method="POST"
        uri-variables-expression="@uriVariableBean.populateTicketSumUrl(payload)"
        extract-request-payload="true"
        expected-response-type="mypackage.dto.bet.SlipAddTransactionsResultWrapper">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Note that I am using uriVariableBean in another gateway that has been defined in the same file, and that gateway works, so its definitely not a problem with importing that bean, I just have not pasted the code.

Here is the relevant code from the bean:

```
@Value("${vfl.tickets.sum}")
private String defaultVirtualTicketsAddress;

@Value("${vfl.tickets.sum.ba}")
private String specialVirtualTicketsAddress;

public Map<String, ?> populateTicketSumUrl(Object payload) {

        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (payload instanceof SlipDataRequest) {

            BetSlipDataRequest dataRequest = (SlipDataRequest) payload;

            Integer lcMemberId = dataRequest.getLcMemberId() != null ? dataRequest.getLcMemberId().intValue() : null;

            if (webUserService.isSpecial(lcMemberId)) {

                variables.put("ticketsSum", specialVirtualTicketsAddress);
            } else {

                variables.put("ticketsSum", defaultVirtualTicketsAddress);
            }

        } else {

            variables.put("ticketsSum", EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers.ticketsSum"));
        }

        return variables;
    }
```

The error I get when invoking an operation using the gateway is the following:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 8): Field or property 'ticketsSum' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.integration.MessageHeaders'
```

Any insight on why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated, as I have went through the documentation and all the online posts I could find and still have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the message being sent doesn't have that header. DEBUG logging is always your fried.

When accessing headers, it's generally better to use the map accessor `headers['ticketsSum']` rather than the property accessor `headers.ticketsSum` because the former will resolve to `null` for a missing header, whereas the latter will throw the exception you observe.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your answer.

However, shouldn't the bean's populateTicketSumUrl method have added the headers to the message? The way I understood the documentation, the

    variables.put("ticketsSum", specialVirtualTicketsAddress);

should put the specialVirtualTicketsAddress value into a header named ticketsSum. Or am I way off with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you're way off but `url="{ticketsSum}"` requires a `ticketSum` variable, and `variables.put("ticketsSum", EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers.ticketsSum"));` is populating the `ticketSum` variable with the contents of the `ticketSum` header (which doesn't exist in this case).